# Error when combining authenticated and anonymous access to one database

Tags: xpages

I have existing Xpages app for authenticated users only. Now I need to create a two new Xpages and allow annonymous access to them. To do this I added 'Read Public Access documents'  do Anonymous user. Now I can see these 2 Xpages anonymously but sudenly existing non-anonymous part of application doesnt work anymore and app raises Dojo errors in browser as below. Scenario is like this:

Tested on Domino 9.01 and 9.0.1FP3 + Chrome with the same results

1. I open non-anonymous app in browser and authenticate, it works
   correctly for now
2. from different browser I open the anonymous Xpage that works fine
   also
3. now I refresh (F5 in browser) the non-anonymus app from point a) and it starts raise errors as below. I need to restart http to fix it.

I tested this scenario several times on my local and customers server with the same result. I found this  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO76577 ... but is there any workaround for this scenario? Or how to combine anonymous and authenticated access in one app properly?

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8090/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.3/dojo/require.js"
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8090/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.3/ibm/xsp/widget/layout/layers/nls/xspClientDojo_cs.js".

dojo.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dynamic' of undefined_bc @ dojo.js:15_31 @ dojo.js:15_f4 @ dojo.js:15def @ dojo.js:15(anonymous function) @ xspClientDojo.js:5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That technote sounds wrong. I've had anonymous and authenticated access in an NSF running fine in production for many years, first deployed on 8.5.1.

My XPage is public access, but the custom control for the layout isn't.

I can't see how point 2 (another user opening on another browser) can impact it.

Based on the word "dynamic" in the error, do you have a dynamic content control in the relevant page? If you're on the same page when you authenticate, I would look at the code running after authentication and whether that changes JS variables or the component tree which means something is then not available to code running on load of the page.

Comment: Its really strange, what I found by testing on collegues computers is that problem occures in latest Chrome 48. My 2 collegues have Chrome 47 and its working fine. After upgrading one to Chrome 48 it doesnt work for him :-(. Problem is reproducible ... form that submits raises error after next GET request. F5 refresh causes dojo error, Shift+F5 fixes this temporary.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with Dojo and Chrome 48 rather than anything specific to the server-side public access settings then. I had a quick search and can't see any obvious links.

Comment: Hmm I just tested different Xpages apps with Chrome 48 and these have the same issues ... because of this ... dojo fails to bind onclick events, XSP is not loaded so app become unresponsive ...

Comment: It's been confirmed as a regression bug in Chrome 48, see http://planetlotus.org/d84794